# Unable to applyEdits ArcGIS FeatureLayer

Tags: javascript, html, input, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Good Evening,

I am trying to update my featureLayer using the applyEdits properties. I am facing some issues as I cannot change the value of the specific layer. I am not sure what is wrong here do assist me on this, cheers! (This project is running on ArcGIS API 3.25)

```
 let testButton = document.getElementById('testButton')
    if (testButton){
    testButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
      var announcementInput = document.getElementById('announcementInput').value;
      console.log(announcementInput)
 
      featureLayer.applyEdits(
                  null,
                  [{
                    "attributes":{
                      "objectid":objectid,
                      "announcement": announcementInput, // I want to update this value
                  }
                  }],
                  null,
                  null,
                  null
    })
    }
    else{
      console.log("Not working")
    }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need to pass `Graphic` elements, you are just passing an object. It should be something like this,

```
// first get the feature you want to edit
const query = new Query();
query.objectIds = [objectid];
query.outFields = [ "*" ];
featureLayer.queryFeatures(query, function(featureSet) {
    if (featureSet.features.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    // now update the desire attribute
    const feature = featureSet.features[0];
    feature.attributes.announcement = announcementInput;
    featureLayer.applyEdits(
      null,
      [feature],
      null,
      null,
      null
    })
});
```

Comment: I see, yes I did not pass in the graphic elements for this. This worked thank you very much!